# Android studio custom templates

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

How can I create a custom jetpack-compose template, so I can avoid making the same changes over and over again to gradle and other files every time I start a new project?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can write an Android Studio Plugin, search Google for some tutorials. There are quite a lot development and maintenance works to do though.

Answer (score 1):

You could create yourself a starter project on git, and then clone that each time.